# When implementing an interface, how do you implement an indexer property?

Tags: c#, com, interface-implementation

I'm working with a COM API that was created in another language, and I'm accessing it with C#.  I'm trying to implement one of the interfaces, but I'm seeing an error in VS that says:

'MyClass' does not implement interface member 'InterfaceName.MemberName[object].set'.".

I've searched around, and learned a bit about indexer properties (which I think this is).  However, I still can't figure out how to implement this interface member.

The code I cobbled together looks like this

```
private string[] membername= new string[10];
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("MemberName")]
public string this[object index]
{
    get
    {
        return membername[(int)index];
    }
    set
    {
        membername[(int)index] = value;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

In the documentation that I'm working from, this is the example that's given.

```
Public Property MemberName( _
   ByVal Index As Variant _
) As String
```

Comment: It sounds like your interface has a (non-default) indexed property.  C# has no syntax to declare that.

Comment: Add the interface to the question. The pseudoanonymization of names are contraproductive.

Comment: What does the signature for the indexer look like in the interface? For example, you have it as type `string` in your class, but we have no way of seeing if that's what the interface specifies.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in this situation, you can't use the syntactic sugar of `{ get; set; }`.  You actually have to create the underlying methods for the get and set of the indexed property.

The working code looks like this...

```
private string[] MemberName = new string[10];
public string get_MemberName(object Index)
{
    return MemberName[(int)Index];
}

public void set_MemberName(object Index, string Value)
{
    MemberName[(int)Index] = Value;
}
```